# Limit is infinite or finite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, taylor-expansion

The  given  function  is  $${{Log\  z}\over {z-1}}=1- {1\over 2}(z-1)+ {1\over 3} (z-1)^2-{1\over 4}(z-1)^3+.... $$
Then it is  said  that  *the function tends to $+\infty$ as $z$ tends to $0$* . But  how $?$ As  $z$   tends  to  $0$  the  function  tends  to  $$1-{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}-{1\over 4}  +....$$  which  is  a  convergent  series  hence  the  sum  is  $\lt  \infty$  ,  i.e.   some  finite  number .  So  how  can  it  " tend  to  $+\infty $" $?$

Please  explain.

Comment: If you plug $z=0$ in the RHS, you get $$1+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+{1\over 4}  +\ldots=+\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

You've got the wrong sign. At $z=0$ the series becomes
$$
1+{1\over 2}+{1\over 3}+{1\over 4}  +\ldots
$$
which is divergent.